# Laravel POST request return 204 response

Tags: php, laravel

i am developing an api with laravel.
At the time of making a POST request it returns 204 "No body return for response" being that to test it I answer a code 200.

```
public function create(Request $request){
  return response()->json(['data' => 'work'], 200);
}
```

I've done insomnia tests locally and they were successful.

All get methods work correctly, while all my POST methods return the same answer 204

This is my api.php

```
Route::get('usuarios/{idgoogle}', 'UsuarioController@buscar');
Route::post('usuarios/create', 'UsuarioController@create');
Route::post('usuarios/modificar', 'UsuarioController@modificarUbicacion');

Route::post('usuarios/modificarEstado', 'UsuarioController@modificarEstado');
```

And the rest of my controller

```
public function buscar($idGoogle){

  $user = \App\User::where('id_google', $idGoogle)->get();


  if(!$user->isEmpty()){
    return response()->json($user, 200);
  }else{
    return response()->json(['data' => 'data not found'], 204);
  }

}

public function modificarUbicacion(Request $request){

  if($request->apiKey != env('APP_KEY')){
      return response()->json(['data' => 'unauthorized'], 401);
  }

  $user = \App\User::where('id_google', $request->id_google)->firstOrFail();



  $user->last_latitude = $request->latitude;
  $user->last_longitude = $request->longitude;
  $user->save();

  return response()->json($user, 200);

}

public function modificarEstado(Request $request){

  if($request->apiKey != env('APP_KEY')){
      return response()->json(['data' => 'unauthorized'], 401);
  }

  $user = \App\User::where('id_google', $request->id_google)->firstOrFail();

  $user->id_estado = $request->id_estado;
  $user->save();

  return response()->json($user, 200);

}
```

Comment: share your api call code and other methods from controller also ?

Comment: yes, they are in the same controller

Comment: It may due to calling wrong method. share your api calling code and other code from controller.

Comment: I was wrong, the problem is in all POST methods when I upload the files to my server, since they all work locally

Comment: ok so your problem is solved with `get` request ?

Comment: no, i need to use a POST request to create the users in the database, but when uploading my project to my server, these requests only respond with a 204 code without doing what is written in the method

Comment: any idea what happens? I made test requests while the project was in local and they work perfectly